# How to CONCAT and GROUP BY rows in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, concatenation, row

Here is the table I have. Each column is representing as a result of a subquery.

```
id | A     | B     | C     | (and many columns)
---+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+-----+-...
 1 | 1a3b  | 1a2b  | 4a1b  |          |
 2 | 7a3b  | 3a7b  | 7a7b  |          |
 3 | 2a3b  | 1a3b  | 3a6b  |          |
 4 | 6a3b  | 6a3b  | 6a3b  |          |
```

There are many columns in my table, not only A, B and C.
The result is generate by `CONCAT` method.

```
SELECT CONCAT(A,B,C,...) FROM myTable
```

That's what I got. Not the answer I want.

```
id | A     | B     | C     | result        |
---+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
 1 | 1a3b  | NULL  | 4a1b  | 1a3b4a1b      |
 2 | 7a3b  | 3a7b  | 7a3b  | 7a3b3a7b7a3b  |
 3 | 2a3b  | 1a3b  | 3a6b  | 2a3b1a3b3a6b  |
 4 | 6a3b  | 6a3b  | 6a3b  | 6a3b6a3b6a3b  |
```

I can't find a way to `"group by"` the rows and get the result like below to remove(or not CONCAT)the repeat value. Is that any way to do that?

```
id | A     | B     | C     | result        |
---+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
 1 | 1a3b  | NULL  | 4a1b  | 1a3b4a1b      |
 2 | 7a3b  | 3a7b  | 7a3b  | 7a3b3a7b      |
 3 | 2a3b  | 1a3b  | 3a6b  | 2a3b1a3b3a6b  |
 4 | 6a3b  | 6a3b  | 6a3b  | 6a3b          |
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: What do you mean by `Each column is representing as a result of a subquery.` and `There are many rows in my table, not only A, B and C.` ?

Comment: @Squirrel The subquery is a result of string so you can handle it same as string. For 2nd sentence I made a mistake. "There are many `column` in my table, not only A, B and C." instead of `rows`.

Comment: @Zhorov My version is "Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor) "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach, based on `VALUES` table-value constructor and `FOR XML`, is an option:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (1, '1a3b', NULL,   '4a1b'),
   (2, '7a3b', '3a7b', '7a3b'),
   (3, '2a3b', '1a3b', '3a6b'),
   (4, '6a3b', '6a3b', '6a3b')
) v (id, A, B, C)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   result = (
      SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('', c)
      FROM (VALUES (A), (B), (C)) v (c)
      FOR XML PATH('')   
   )
FROM Data
```

Result:

```
id A    B    C    result
-------------------------------
1  1a3b Null 4a1b 1a3b4a1b
2  7a3b 3a7b 7a3b 3a7b7a3b
3  2a3b 1a3b 3a6b 1a3b2a3b3a6b
4  6a3b 6a3b 6a3b 6a3b
```

Comment: There is a 'v' in the line "FROM (VALUES (A), (B), (C)) v (c)". What is the name, function about that 'v'? I've never see that before.

Comment: @Clyde It's an alias for the `VALUES` [table-value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) constructor. And an example from the same [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-specifying-multiple-values-as-a-derived-table-in-a-from-clause).

Answer (score 1):

If I've got it right

```
select id,A,B,C, string_agg(s, '')
from mytable 
cross apply (
     select distinct s
     from ( values(A),(B),(C)) t(s)
) t(s)
group by id,A,B,C
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query should work:

```sql
DECLARE @table table(id int, a char(4), b char(4), c char(4))

insert into @table values
(2 ,'7a3b','3a7b','7a3b')

SELECT a,b,c, string_agg(t1.dval,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a,b,c)) as conc
from @table as ot
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT DISTINCT val from
(
VALUES
(left(a,2)),
(right(a,2)),
(left(b,2)),
(right(b,2)),
(left(c,2)),
(right(c,2))
)t(val)
) as t1(dval)
group by a,b,c
```